# Apache Phoenix csvbulkloadTool failed

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, secondary-indexes

I am using the following Linux command:

```html
hadoop jar phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-0.98-client.jar org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool --table TT --input /tmp/text.csv
```

This command works successfully, but no data from csv file is loaded in hbase table, but data is loaded to the index table successfully (import csv file for TT's index table).

environment：

HBASE 0.98.9

hadoop 2.6.0

Phoenix 4.6-hbase-0.98

***case 1：index covered all columns***

1)

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    my_pk bigint not null,
    m.first_name varchar(50),
    m.last_name varchar(50)
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (my_pk))
```

2)

```
CREATE INDEX index_example on example(m.last_name ASC) include (m.first_name)
   or create index index_example on example(m.first_name,m.last_name)
```

3)

```
hadoop jar phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-0.98-client.jar org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool --table example --input /tmp/text1.csv --index-table INDEX_EXAMPLE
```

4)

```
select * from example
```

SUCCESS  AND   HAVE DATA

```
select * from index_example
```

SUCCESS  AND HAVE DATA

testcase:
org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadToolIT.testImportWithIndex()

***case 2：index covered part of columns***

1)

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    my_pk bigint not null,
    m.first_name varchar(50),
    m.last_name varchar(50)
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (my_pk))
```

2)

```
create index index_example on example(m.last_name ASC)
```

3)

```
hadoop jar phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-0.98-client.jar 
org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool --table example --input /tmp/text1.csv --index-table INDEX_EXAMPLE
```

4)

```
select * from example
```

SUCCESS   BUT NO DATA

```
select * from index_example
```

SUCCESS HAVE DATA

testcase:
org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadToolIT.testImportOneIndexTable()

Comment: Can you post the queries that you create the table and its index? Also a sample data in your csv file.

Comment: CSV file like this:
12345,John,Doe

Comment: You can simply edit your question and post them there.

Comment: Are you sure there is no data? Did you try to scan the tables in hbase? Maybe the query is using the table/index that you don't expect.

Comment: I have edited my question。I`m sure there is no data,I checked the hbase table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Phoenix, when your table name is in lowercase.
You need to cover them with double quotes

```
    hadoop jar phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-0.98-client.jar 
org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvBulkLoadTool --table \"\"example\"\" --input /tmp/text1.csv --index-table INDEX_EXAMPLE
```